# Joomla and SEO Friendly URLs

Tags: php, joomla, seo

For example http://www.mysite.com is my site and I created some demo site with same server called http://www.mysite.com/new for implementing SEO Friendly urls.Is there any plugin available to do creating SEO Friendly urls or can we do this by .htaccess?

Joomla Version 1.5.22.

Please guide me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User friendly urls is a feature of joomla since version 1.5 .

If you are using apache, change the htaccess.txt to .htaccess and uncomment the part that does the url rewriting.

You'll have to enable Search Engine Friendly URLs in the  Global Configuration.

Here's the wiki page of joomla on how to enable search engine friendly urls:
http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs

Comment: In addition to the above information (which is the correct answer); you should upgrade.  1.5.22 is old, and open to security problems.  Upgrade to the latest, and if you can think about getting to migrate to their next LTS (1.8).

Comment: I'll just add one slight correction - SEF URLs have been a part of Joomla since Joomla 1.0 and were definitely a part of its predecessor (Mambo) long before that. Joomla 1.5 SEF URLs were a definite improvement though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting call "SEO Settings" in Global Configuration. You can easily change the mode of URL displaying and can make it SEO Friendly. Please check below image to get more idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting call "SEO Settings" in Global Configuration. You can easily change the mode of URL displaying and can make it SEO Friendly. Please check below image to get more idea.